# invoice package and graphicx

Tags: graphics, invoice

I'm writing an invoice with the `dinbrief` class (it occurs with `letter` too), using the `invoice` package and I want to include my signature as image. However, I'm running into mysterious errors even with a very simple example.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{invoice}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\recipient}{%
    Mr. Wong\\%
    This street
}

\address{%
    Hey, it is\\%
    me living here
}
\signature{My} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{\recipient} 
        \opening{Dear..} 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen} 
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Using the code as above gives me a weird first page containing dates

[image]

Using `\usepackage{graphix}` as last import, gives an error

```
Missing \begin{document}. \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[..
I can't find file `keyval,graphics.sty'. RequirePackage{keyval,graphics}
```

What is wrong here and how am I supposed to include images?

Comment: I get no error; note however that the `german` package is obsolete and should be `\usepackage[german]{babel}`. It's also better to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with texlive2016 and pdflatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error in the way `invoice.sty` accesses `fp` it has

```
\input{fp}
```

If you edit a local copy  to say

```
\RequirePackage{fp}
```

then it works (my local copy was already edited, which probably means this question is a duplicate and i was answering before...)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry that it is a duplicate. I searched google before did not find the link to the answer.